# digitalOcean meteor js mup deploy

Tags: meteor, digital-ocean

i've deployed my meteor application on digitalOcean 512Mo droplet , and it is stuck in the first step "uploading bundle" it takes so long without any response no error also, mup setup works fine. This is not the first deployment i've deployed before few times it was working fine. i've tried to disable the firewall and it doesn't work. i have also a local staging server i've tried to deploy and it works fine but its 2G Ram , shall i upgrate the droplet.

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to determine without more information. Did you disable the firewall on the droplet?

Comment: yes, just temporary to see if the firewall is the problem.

Comment: Try running `sudo tcpdump -i eth0 not port 22` on the droplet to see what happens. Also, while uploading you could look at the processes on the droplet with `ps aux`, find the receiving process and run `strace` on it to find out what the receiving process is doing.